# Edge SharePoint Online import spreadsheet Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, migration, import, browser-compatibility, spreadsheet

Within Sharepoint Online and Edge browser, I try to use the **Import Spreadsheet** app 
[image]

I get the next error

[image]

I wonder if someone can help me to workaround this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , **ActiveX don’t work with Edge browser** based on this official article from Microsoft [Issues that occur when you use the Edge browser with Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3083635)

The only workaround to do that to use another browser like Internet Explorer or Google Chrome